# Why do we say "there is butter on your chin", not "there is the butter on your chin"?

Tags: word-usage, articles, phrase-usage, definite-articles

Now I looked at your face & I saw some butter on your chin. I know what **specific butter** it is.

But why do I still say "**there is butter on your chin**", why not "**there is the butter on your chin**"?

[This is a question of a test.](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/multi/article1.htm)

> Q36: There's ..... butter on your chin.
>
> A: the
>
> B: no article

Do you choose A or B?

The correct answer is B

Comment: Just so know, it would be hard but not impossible to create a scene that calls for *the butter*, but that's not enough to justify it as normal English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice of article is determined by whether or not *the listener* is already aware of the thing being talked about. Saying "the butter" implies that you expect the listener to already know that the butter exists; saying "some butter" (or "a bit of butter" or just "butter") implies that you're pointing out the existence of some butter that the listener was not already aware of.

The phrase "there is" is almost always used to point out the existence of something that the listener wasn't aware of, so we would almost always say "there's some butter on your chin" or "there's butter on your chin."

The only time you'd say "there's the butter on your chin" is if the listener was previously aware of the butter, but they later forgot about the butter, and you wanted to remind them about the butter. Needless to say, that would be very unusual.

Comment: The listener ate the butter himself so he must have known that specific butter. I think the speaker says "butter" without articles because there is no need to prefer to any specific butter, not because the listener doesn't know like you said. Similarly, Son & Dad re watching children playing in the pool. Would Dad say "Look, they're splashing water onto each other" or "Look, they're splashing the water onto each other". I think the former's better because both speakers and listener don't care about whether it's the specific water or not, although they can see what kind of specific water it is.

Answer (score 1):

The simple reason is that there is nothing specific about the butter you are talking about in this case, it's just a little bit of butter, and therefore you have to treat the term "butter" as a mass noun, nouns which do not take articles. This is just as you don't say (usually) things like "You make cakes with the flour."; you have to say "with flour".

You could, however, use a determiner, which comes much to the same thing as using no determiner at all, and say this.

- There is some butter on your chin.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that 'butter' is a **mass noun**. A mass noun is one which names substances and concepts "in the mass" rather than as countable objects and instances. Other examples are 'sand', 'water' and 'concrete'. A characteristic of mass nouns is that the things they name must be measured or weighed rather than counted. For example "one kilogramme of butter", "two buckets of sand" or "ten tonnes of concrete"

The opposite of a mass noun is a **countable noun** which names things or concepts which occur in discrete units. Examples are 'bricks', 'chairs' and 'books' so we say things like "one thousand bricks", " four chairs" and "half a dozen books".

Note that you can refer to quantities of things named by countable nouns merely by preceding them with a number such as "four chairs" but quantities of things named by mass nouns need a suitable unit of measure, for instance "one kilogramme of butter". Saying "one butter" is not, normally, meaningful.

The fact that "butter" is a mass noun means that using an article whether definite (the) or indefinite (a or an) is usually as meaningless as using a number with it. That's why we say "There is butter on your chin". We could use a unit such as "there is *a spot* of butter on your chin" but not "there is *the* butter on your chin.

Sometimes countable nouns can be used as mass nouns and mass nouns can be used in a similar way to countable nouns  which is confusing. An example of this would be "a tonne of bricks" where the bricks are being considered by weight rather than by number or "a deep yellow butter" or "a quick-setting concrete" but in those cases we are "counting" the *type* of butter or concrete rather than the *amount* of it. We might say "weigh a kilogramme of a rich, creamy butter' but we would not say "Weigh a kilogramme of a butter" because 'butter' is a mass noun.

There is one case where we might say "*the* butter" but that is where there is an identifiable quantity of butter somewhere (for example in a dish on the table, or in the ingredient list of a recipe). We might say "pass the butter please" meaning "pass the butter in the dish" or, in a recipe, "melt the butter in a pan" meaning "melt the quantity of butter specified in the ingredient list". The nearest you can get to your sentence "There is the butter on your chin" is "There is *a knob* of *the* butter on your chin. But in this case there is an identifiable source (the butter on the table, perhaps) and a unit of measure (a knob of butter).

Comment: 'Butter' is an uncountable or 'mass' noun, but that's entirely irrelevant here. "Please pass me the butter", for example. There's no difference between mass nouns, singular count nouns or plural nouns when it comes to the definite article ( unlike with the indefinite article). The quality of your writing's great, but your answer is wrong.